# stop ' changing into &#39; when c# converts to html

Tags: javascript, c#

So here is a strange question.

I have some code in `C#` which generates some `Html` code. However the `'` converts into `&#39;` and that doesn't work with my `javascript`. How can I get around this problem. Is there some kind of change I can do in my `javascript` or in my `C#` code?

The code:

```
@{
    string toolTip = hasChild ? "data-toggle='tooltip' title='Expand'" : "data-toggle='tooltip' title='Read'";

    <a href="#" onclick="showSubLevel(@current.articleId);" @toolTip><span class="@icon"></span></a> // This doesn't work
    @Html.ActionLink(current.title, "Read", "Entry", new { id = e.Value.articleId }, new { data_toggle="tooltip", title="Read" }) // This works
}

<script>
    $(function () {
        $('[data-toggle="tooltip"]').tooltip()
    })
</script>
```

I've also tried:

```
string toolTip = hasChild ? "data-toggle=&#39;tooltip&#39; title=&#39;Expand&#39;" : "data-toggle=&#39;tooltip&#39; title=&#39;Read&#39;";
toolTip = System.Web.HttpUtility.HtmlDecode(toolTip);
```

but it didn't work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use [`Raw`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg568896(v=vs.111).aspx) in razor to avoid automatic HTML encoding.

Try this:

```
@{
    string toolTip = hasChild ? "data-toggle='tooltip' title='Expand'" : "data-toggle='tooltip' title='Read'";

    <a href="#" onclick="showSubLevel(@current.articleId);" @Html.Raw(toolTip)><span class="@icon"></span></a> // This doesn't work
    @Html.ActionLink(current.title, "Read", "Entry", new { id = e.Value.articleId }, new { data_toggle="tooltip", title="Read" }) // This works
}
```

Please note the `@Html.Raw(tooltip)` in the code.

Comment: Ofcourse. Why didn't I think of that ^^ Will mark this solved